# Multiple student course enrolment report

Tags: excel, report

I am trying to prepare a report that tells me how many students have done course ABC and course XYZ.

Our data output contains one record per student per course. So if a student has done more than 1 course, they will appear in the data for how many courses they have done.

The ideal outcome is to get a matrix styled report that looks like below:

```
Course Names          Course A   Course B   Course C   Course D
Course A                  -         5          0          20
Course B                  5         -          6           7
Course C                  0         6          -           1
Course D                  20        7          1           -
```

Can anyone suggest a solution to achieve this?

Comment: So your question is confusing because you mention courses X,Y,Z but do not show them in your question.  And the matrix is 50% wasted as it is diagonally symmetric. That said, I suggest you look into Excel's Pivot Tables.  Using a Pivot Table as an intermediate result will allow you to organize all the student course data, in particular if Students are the rows and Courses are the columns, you can quickly use other columns to calculate students taken multiple classes.  Then you can utilize the Pivot Table plus the calculations to probably create a matrix similar to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Cybermike is correct. Use the pivot table functionality to get the count of students who have taken both, one, or the other.

You could use Countifs formulas for creating a more complex set of conditional criteria to build your own pivot table, but start with the insert pivot table function on the ribbon.